# How ASP.NET Session.Timeout Works

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

What happens if a timeout is set to 20 minutes, and the user clicks on a button at minute 19. Do they get another 20 minutes?

Comment: "Session timeout represents the event occuring when a user do not perform any action on a web site during a interval (defined by web server). The event, on server side, change the status of the user session to 'invalid' (ie. "not used anymore") and instruct the web server to destroy it (deleting all data contained into it)." - owasp.org

Comment: In other words. Yes. that's what happens. The session is basically timing out if the user doesn't perform any action on the site.

Comment: Also check if you have sliding expiration set, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes, the 20 minutes time is the default setting of the IIS web service, If you want to customize this setting you can modify your web.config file.
Here are the info and an example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout